# What Japanese font is used in the Try Knights logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

Attempted to use https://en.likefont.com to no avail

Sample from: https://www.ntv.co.jp/tryknights/

[image: Try Knights logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logos are usually designed specifically for the title -- so you won't find a font that will be able to write out the name. Sometimes people make full fonts based on a title like "Jurassic Park"

Something like *GN Kill Gothic U* might be a good start and then you would have to change the kerning and maybe add some flourishes in Illustrator or Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Try Knights (in english) is Copperplate. Many foundries offer a variation of it. Simply search for it online.